# RoR selecting newest "distinct by column" rows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table which I use to log item price change over time.
I'm trying to write a method which grabs the entire set of items (without duplicates), together with their latest prices.

That means that a row with an item_id of 2 may appear several times inside my table, and a row with an item_id of 3 may appear several times inside the table etc', but the result should only include them once, with their latest price

I'm trying to figure out a way (without using Item.find_by_sql() if possible), to return the entire set of items and their latest prices.

Currently I have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM item_logs   
 ORDER BY created_at DESC) inner_table
GROUP BY item_id
```

It does work, but it seems wrong to do it like this, I guess i'm looking for a more elegant way to do this, since current implementation requires me to use find_by_sql which is not very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

not sure it's any better, but another option would be use joins:

```
ItemLog.joins(
  'join (select item_id, max(created_at) as created_at from item_logs group by 1) 
   as i on i.item_id = item_logs.item_id and i.created_at = item_logs.created_at'
)
```

longer than your find_by_sql solution, could be a more expensive query on your database, but keeps the result as an active record relation so you can chain other methods on.